# Small parasite wasps around the soil

Tags: houseplants, pest-control, pests, parasites

Recently i detect many small black parasite wasps (not talking about **Fungus Gnats**)
They are flying smoothly and searching the surface of the soil (around the indoor pots).

I don't know if they are helpful or harmful ?

Also I want to know name of this insects.

### Edit

plants are vary by many types(mimosa plant, Stapelia gigantea, ricrac cactus, red and yellow Millet, Parsley), i know the wasp's comes from a **Stapelia gigantea** and then proliferated in this 3 months (about 10 wasps). **about the used soild**: i used a **vermicompost**, i bought it vacuumed and bagged firmly! *the only pet i scouted inside the soil, is Fungus Gnat*

***attached some pictures of them and pots***

[image: Picture 1]
[image: Picture 2]
[image: Picture 3]
[image: Picture 4 - pots]

---

they are small as **0.5mm** x **2mm** and always exploring the surface and inside of the soil holes.

Comment: This is kind of hard to answer. How do you know they are parasitic wasps? What animals do they use as host? Where do you live?

Comment: @b.nota hi and tnx for attention, i check them by magnifier and they was wasp. looks like bigger ones i saw around caterpillars in past. I know there is some fungus gnats in the pot also some very small worms like earthworms. My location is middle eastern

Comment: You mention 'pot',which suggestst this is a potted plant - is it indoors or outdoors? How big is the pot, what's the plant that's in it and how long have you had the plant in that pot? Any chance of a photo of the pot and plant concerned?Parasitic wasps are looking for something to prey upon, which suggests whatever they're looking for is already in your pot's soil - but that shoiuld not be the case with a potted plant, so more info regarding the plant and pot, as mentioned above, please.

Comment: My question is did you use potting soil, sterilized, bagged soil from the store or did you use soil from your garden?  We gotta have pictures.  To diagnose anything going by just the written word is sort of irresponsible.  Ask a friend to help.  We get great close ups all the time.  Parasitic wasps will die soon because there is nothing to parasitize!  In the garden, there will always be available food.  Not in a pot.

Comment: @Bamboo thanks for attention. post is Updated

Comment: @stormy thanks a lot for guidance's,  i put some pictures, hope they will come handy.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure, but I think a soap water will get rid off them.

Comment: I guess they are not harmful for plants, i shall protect them if this is true, otherwise killing them with your approach

Comment: @payam_sbr it shouldn't really kill them. This is a very common approach against parasites :)